# MVC 4 Web API - Routes for composite keys

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm struggling to work out the routing configuration needed to support the following simple scenario:

```
http..service/api/objects/key1/key2
```

I feel like I've tried everything.

The biggest problem is that whenever it looks like I've cracked it, I find that

```
http..service/api/objects/key1
```

gets routed to the parameterless IQueryable Get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've nailed it.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: IQueryableObjectsApiRouteName,
    routeTemplate: "api/objects",
    defaults: new { controller = "objects" }
);

routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: ObjectsApiRouteName,
    routeTemplate: "api/objects/{siteId}/{assetId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "objects", siteId = "", assetId = "" }
);
```

I need to setup two explicit routes to each controller with composite keys. The default values for the keys are "", which I detect in the controller and throw my own 404.

It works for me. I can go to lunch now.

Comment: could you specify your controller method parameters? :) I would like to know how it looks with composite key

Comment: Sorry Roylee, I've left that contract/client. I would expect that it would simply be `public SomeModel Get(string siteId, string assetId)` though.